# Create new column based on matching values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked through the other answers for Operand errors and none of them seem to fit this example !

I'm trying to create new pandas column based on condition from another dataframe.The two dataframes haven't the same shape (194802 rows against 9 rows).

I have tried this code so far:

```
for index in range(len(df_segment)):
df_segment['cible'] = np.where((df_filtre_client["montant_com"]>df_segment.iloc[index]['ca']) & \
                                (df_filtre_client["nb_months"]>df_segment.iloc[index]['nb_mois_strct_sup']) & \
                                (df_filtre_client["nb_months"]<=df_segment.iloc[index]['nb_mois_max']) & \
                                (df_filtre_client["nb_cmd"]>df_segment.iloc[index]['nb_cmd_strct_sup']) & \
                                (df_filtre_client["nb_cmd"]<=df_segment.iloc[index]['nb_cmd_max']) , 1 , df_segment['cible'])
```

But I get this error :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (194802,) () (9,)
```

How can I rid of it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: show the expected result and some rows of data.